# Installing official AMDGPU linux driver with kernel 4.19.x on Debian Buster: cannot apply patch

Tags: debian, amd

Stuck at installing official AMDGPU linux driver 20.45 with kernel 4.19.x on Debian Buster

Here the howto: [complete how-to installing official AMDGPU drivers](https://wiki.debian.org/AMDGPUDriverOnStretchAndBuster2)

At stage 3 need to apply patch. Thus it is not applying, throwing:

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at 192.
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #2 FAILED at 216. 
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.c.rej
```

Reading manuals. Put EOL anywhere I could. Nothing helps.

For now - applied suggested patch manually, and installed AMDGPU drivers.

Thus the question remains: what is wrong with the patch file? It looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange... but... the problem was in tab-spaces...

I've copied file from source. [File](https://wiki.debian.org/AMDGPUDriverOnStretchAndBuster2?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=01-amdgpu_20.40_on_linux_4.19-v3.patch)

But there was wrong 'tabs'.

Edited file and placed normal 'tabs' anywhere they have to be, and patch applied succesfully.